# How to set up a Laravel project in a way that multiple apps with different stacks can be attached to each subdomain?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, server

I've worked with small and isolated Laravel apps in the past, but currently I have a main Laravel project at **domain.com** and would like to put in place a setup where each subdomain would contain an independent application, including a different tech stack, if possible. Just as an example, **blog.domain.com** would have a [Strapi](https://strapi.io/)-powered blog.

I'm currently using Laravel Sail in my development environment and the project is still at its very beginning, so I was even considering whether to go for Apache or NGINX. Essentially, understanding to which extent I need to work on configuring the server may also guide my decision.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the [NGINX Unit](http://unit.nginx.org). It supports plenty of languages and has a howto's for many frameworks (including [laravel](http://unit.nginx.org/howto/laravel/)). Here is an example of configuration for several apps (PHP, Python, NodeJS, Ruby, Perl, Java, etc.): http://unit.nginx.org/configuration/#full-example

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I'm wondering if I'm not over-complicating things. If what I want are subdomains with independent applications, isn't it the case of simply setting up virtual hosts on my server so that they serve my apps under xxx.domain.com, yyy.domain.com, etc.? Then — now I hope I'm not oversimplifying — each directory in my main project root would contain the entire code base for an application.